# Unfold tuple in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

Is there any way to apply function to tuple members as function arguments? Or if not, can I anyhow create a function with arbitrary number of arguments and in its body apply some another function to the "tail" as it would be its arguments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the general case, no.  For the case of 2 arguments, you can use the `curry` and `uncurry` functions in the [Batteries extensions to Pervasives](http://thelema.github.com/batteries-included/hdoc/BatPervasives.html).

It *might* be possible to cook something up with the `Obj` module, like the internals of `printf` do, but I would stay far far away from that.  The difficulty is that the type system does not give you a way to express the type of a generalized `curry` or `uncurry` function.  The type system does not let you "compute" over the length of a tuple - a 2-tuple is a 2-tuple and you don't have a way to express that `(a*b*c)` is really `(a*b)` with an additional component.  `printf` has special support from the compiler to make the types work out properly, and it results in the function type being a part of the format type (so similar solutions won't work for tuples).

Answer (score 7):

The language itself does not allow you to define a function on tuples of arbitrary size.

It is however possible to define functions with an arbitrary number of arguments by following [this folding technique](http://mlton.org/Fold) (it's described there for SML but works equally well in OCaml).